# Where is the difference between addEventListener (classic dom svg-elment) and .on (at d3js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling

I face a problem with context-event and its parameter.

Following to versions are used in my site, to attach events:

This approach is used for simple graphic Elements that get their events after loading from database:

```
        const graph = editor.append("g")
        .attr("id", "a" + graphic.Id.toString())
        .html(graphic.SvgString)
        .on("mouseover", graphicMouseOver)
        .on("mouseout", graphicMouseOut)
        .on("mousedown", graphicMouseDown)
        .on("contextmenu", onGraphicContext)
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", graphicDragStart)
            .on("drag", graphicDragging)
            .on("end", graphicDragEnd));
```

Then I have a different approach for some kind of symbols, Ioad to my editor:

```
        const g = editor.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + symbol.SymbolPosition + ")")
        .attr("id", subFunctionId.toString())
        .attr("class", "draggable preview")
        .attr("pointer-events", "fill")
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", symbolDragStart)
            .on("drag", symbolDragging)
            .on("end", symbolDragEnd)
        );
```

Depending on some circumstance, I attach some events to these "symbols" later:

```
function addSymbolEvents(svgSymbols) {
log.debug("addSymbolEvents");
for (var i = 0; i < svgSymbols.length; i++) {
    svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', symbolMouseEnter);
    svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('mouseover', symbolMouseOver);
    svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('mouseout', symbolMouseOut);

    svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', symbolMouseDown);
    svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('dblclick', symbolDblClick);
    svgSymbols[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', symbolRightClick);
}
return svgSymbols;
}
```

If I log the event-parameter the following way, I get `undefined` on `onGraphicContext` and a complete MouseEvent-object on `symbolRightClick`

```
function onGraphicContext(evt) {
    console.log("onGraphicContext", evt);
}

function symbolRightClick(evt) {
    console.log("symbolRightClick", evt);
}
```

What is the difference here? 
Isn't the d3.js-`.on`-attribute the same as `addEventListener`?

Thanks Carsten

Comment: No, it isn't, `.on` is a method of d3 objects, and it may execute some additonal tasks (like normalizing and adding some properties to the event object). The event itself is added using `addEventListener` in that method too.

Comment: And what is the right way to add an eventListener with same parameter like I do with normal DOM Element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selection.on()` is a D3 method, not native JavaScript. Internally, `selection.on()` uses `addEventListener`, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/f8c53bf94712f734f6fce2449e136c12c3d3c5d7/src/selection/on.js#L65).

However, `selection.on()` is not just a wrapper for `addEventListener`. As the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on) says, when you attach a listener using `selection.on()`, that listener...

> ...will be evaluated for the element, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i])

Because of that, `selection.on()` is way more handy for D3 programmers than just using the vanilla `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

As @Teemu wrote it's obviously not the same.
So if you use `.on("contextmenu", onGraphicContext)`, you need to work with the d3.event-object in the event function:

```
function onGraphicContext() {
    console.log("onGraphicContext", d3.event);
}
```

Comment: *"There is no parameter given to the function"*... well, that's incorrect: there are 3 (4 if you count `this` as an argument).

Comment: HI Gerardo, I couldn't follow you. Perhaps it is not the way I expected this but how can I access the parameters? I couldn't log any parameter. Maybe I really didn't understand how to transmit parameters to function but since now, I thought `function xyz(paramA, paramB)`is the way. If I log them, I get only undefined and 0.

Comment: right-click on the green div, please: https://jsfiddle.net/f76cp5nt/2/

Comment: `undefined` and `0` are the expected parameters: `undefined` because there is no data bound and zero is the index of the element in the selection.